# Rspec won't start: undefined local variable or method `it' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am following M.Hartl book

http://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages#sec-spork

and trying to set up rspec testing environment

I do

```
bundle exec spork
```

and expect to see

```
Using RSpec
Loading Spork.prefork block...
Spork is ready and listening on 8989!
```

but instead I get

```
Using RSpec, Rails
Preloading Rails environment
Loading Spork.prefork block...
undefined local variable or method `it' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x00000003985500> (NameError)
/home/boitano/RubyProjects/sample_app/config/routes.rb:44:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/boitano/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/actionpack-4.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:335:in `instance_exec'
...
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: what code is here: `/home/boitano/RubyProjects/sample_app/config/routes.rb:44`?

Comment: Thanks, your question solved mine! There was this "it" in the middle of commented code in routes.rb, I wonder how it got there.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you haven't set up the environment loading or did it with some mistakes (typos ?). Compare the Hartl's [Listing 3.37](http://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages#code-spork_spec_helper) and your spec_helper.rb.